I want to use the same topic as my MA research for a PhD
I believe there's ample room for further exploration within the actual framework of my MA project. I'm very satisfied with how I've organized my work, and the fact that I couldn't fully execute it (the thesis ended up being far more introductory than I intended, due to limitations in time and resources) has revealed the potential for further development. With the right explanations and reasoning, would you recommend that I propose a research project with a very similar structure? As a matter of fact, I intend to pursue a PhD in English rather than my mother tongue. This means I could provide my insights to a different audience. My MA research findings might go to waste if left as they are, and I am still deeply committed to the topic as I have conceptualized it. Any insight?

It is both common and desirable for academic research to get extended and extended over many years, so this is perfectly okay in principle.  If you believe you have a viable research project, I recommend you write up a research proposal to that effect and discuss your idea with the supervisor who supervised your Masters research.  Your previous supervisor should be well-positioned to review your proposal and offer feedback due to their eisting familiarity with the topic and your work on it.

Thank you so much for the input! I will contact my supervisor and ask for their feedback.
